# Autoexpanding label in a list. CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Would like to be able to have all the labels auto expanding to the size of the widest of them. 
Having this html structure:

```
 <div class="body">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <span>
          <label>condition</label>
          <span>used</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>
          <label>with invoice</label>
          <span>yes</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>
          <label>with warranty</label>
          <span>no</span>
      </span>
    </li>
        <li>
      <span>
          <label>with extra large text</label>
          <span>not looking good!</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

and this css:

```
.body {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 300px;
}

.list {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  > li {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    &:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}
  }  
  > li > span {
    background-color: #e0e0e1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #6c777f;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  label {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #a1aab0;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: .5em;
    min-width: 40%;
    padding: .5em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
}
```

is it possible to have all the labels follow the size of the 4th one?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emvidi/qe6bpn14/1/
Updated Fiddle for fluid design: https://jsfiddle.net/emvidi/qe6bpn14/4/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible. But for this you will need to change structure a little bit.

Following HTML structure will be needed:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <label>condition</label>
    <span>used</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>with invoice</label>
    <span>yes</span>
  </li>
  ...
  ...
  <li>
    <label>with invoice</label>
    <span>yes</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

We will make each list item a `table-row` display row and make your `<label>` and `<span>` to behave as `table-cell`.

```
.list {
  border-spacing: 0 10px;  /* border-spacing will be used for gaps between list items */
  display: table;
}
.list > li {
  display: table-row;
}
.list > li > label,
.list > li > span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
.body {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 300px;
}

.list {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}

.list > li {
  background-color: #e0e0e1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #6c777f;
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.list > li > label {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #a1aab0;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 40%;
  padding: .5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.list > li > span {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #e0e0e1;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <label>condition</label>
      <span>used</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>with invoice</label>
      <span>yes</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>with warranty</label>
      <span>no</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>with extra large text</label>
      <span>not looking good!</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thank you for the time, your solution looks good but in a fluid design the list will float to the left. Have a look at the following updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emvidi/qe6bpn14/4/

Comment: @emvidi Well, I think this not looks possible with pure css unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can add `.label{width:150px}` you will have the size you want. But the size never change.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 400px;
}

.list {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.list > li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.list > li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list > li > span {
  background-color: #e0e0e1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #6c777f;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.list label {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #a1aab0;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: .5em;
  min-width: 40%;
  padding: .5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          <span>
              <label>condition</label>
              <span>used</span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
              <label>with invoice</label>
              <span>yes</span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
              <label>with warranty</label>
              <span>no</span>
          </span>
        </li>
            <li>
          <span>
              <label>with extra large text</label>
              <span>not looking good!</span>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at the code, the thing is that I can't know in advance the size and therefore was asking for something that auto expands.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use jQuery to find the longest label and set his width to each other:

```
$(function(){
    var longestLabel = $('label').outerWidth();
    $('label').each(function(){
        if ($(this).outerWidth() > longestLabel) {
            longestLabel = $(this).outerWidth();
        }
    });
    $('label').css('width', longestLabel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to check the widest label like stated before, you could use `nth-last-child(n)` to adjust the width depending on the specified label:

```
$(function() {
   var width = $('li:nth-last-child(1) label').width(); // Only the last label
   $('label').width(width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are familiar with jquery, but if you are this code will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = 0;
    $(".labelWidth").each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > width) {
            width = $(this).width();
        }
    });
    $(".labelWidth").css("width", width+"px");
});
```

Before you run the code you need to set the display of the labels to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

If you want to ensure that they stay on new lines you can simply add

```
float:left; 
clear: both;
```

With jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/Conner160/aztbgo37

Without jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/Conner160/sacfszy4/

Comment: Yes I am but familiar with jQuery but I was looking for a css based solution. Thanks